# Picking a subset out of a greater 2d set?

Tags: c#, java, sorting, data-structures, set

I'm having some objects with attributes x and y (positions). I would like to obtain and process those of the objects that are nearby me (!) but ignore the ones that are out of range (*).

```
 __________________________
|   __________             |
|  |     !    | *          |
|* |         !|      *     |  -me = center of subset
|  |    me    |            |  -!  = elements of subset
|  |  !       |            |  -*  = elements of full set, not visible
|  |_______!__|   *       *|
|__________________________|
```

The slow approach would be to iterate the complete ,unsorted, set, and ignore elements those for which the distance is too big. However i'm going to have a big dataset, and need quite some performance.

Instead I'm looking for a way to select only the nearby elements to start with. Maybe by sorting the 2d set in some way, and only iterate the set over a certain range (from the subset's border to border).

Is there a good way to do this?

(note: the objects' positions are static, and the set can be pre-processed)

Comment: Are the X and Y lat and long?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Construct a [quadtree](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quadtree) containing all your points.

Given query rectangle R and quad tree root node Q, the pseudocode for the query algorithm is as follows.

```
query(Rectangle R, QuadTreeNode Q)
    if R and Q.bounds are disjoint
        yield no points
    else if R contains Q.bounds
        yield all points in the subtree of Q
    else (if R intersects Q.bounds)
        yield all points in query(R, Q.child[i]) for i = 0, 1, 2, 3
```

This assumes a `QuadTreeNode` has `Rectangle bounds` and `QuadTreeNode child[4]`.

Comment: Great! Didn't know about it, but now I've implemented one. I achieved between about 40 to 70% increase in performance, depending on the iteration.

Comment: @user717572 Good to hear. :) An optimized implementation can often give you gains much larger than even that (depending on how large your point set is). Another thing to note is that the query region `R` doesn't necessarily have to be a rectangle. The same exact algorithm will work for other query shapes - for example, a circle.